# Looping to pass multiple values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am working on one of the requirement where I need to take records from a table and then pass those records into a query. Ideally if I am getting 4 records from the first query then below query should check the value for all those 4 records. can someone help here?

```
select stop_num from shipment_stop where shipment_gid = 'XYZ' and stop_type = 'P'
```

This query will give me 4 records like i.e. 1,2,3,4
Now I want to pass all these values(1,2,3,4) to one of my query to for further processing. I believe I need to write a loop for this.

Answer (score 0):

Loop is one option, but - processing *row-by-row* is usually *slow-by-slow*. You won't notice any difference on small data sets, but performance will suffer when there's a lot of data involved.

Therefore, you could use your current query as a subquery, like this:

```
select whatever
from some_other_table
where stop_num in (select stop_num
                   from shipment_stop
                   where shipment_gid = 'XYZ'     
                     and stop_type = 'P'
                  );
```

What will you do now depends on you; you never described it.